# What is the speed of the tram?

Tags: word-problem

Every day on her way to school, Sania crosses a tram coming from the opposite direction, at a certain point on the street, at a fixed time. She left 12 minutes early one day and met the tram 3 minutes before the usual time. If she walks at 5.5 km/hr, what is the speed of the tram?

Comment: Did you draw a picture with the usual meeting point, the new meeting point and where she was at the usual meeting time?  How far from the usual meeting point did she meet the tram?

Comment: Yes you can say that......   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tram

Comment: @RossMillikan That has not been stated.

Comment: You are supposed to think about the problem to arrive at that number.  It is a step on the way.

Comment: The distance would be 5.5*(9/60) km

Comment: That is right.  That distance saved the tram $3$ minutes.

Comment: Yes got it , thanks :)

Comment: Oh wait there is something called "tram". English is my foreign language so I thought this word doesn't exist.

Comment: Hehe, come to Kolkata, India. I will make you ride one :)

Comment: you can think of the problem like this, usual day sania at p1 but tram starts at p3 travelling with x km/min for 12 min and reaching p2(p3 is as such distance from p2) and from p2 train travels at speed of x+5.5/60 km/min reaching p1 with total time t min, another day sania standing at a point p1 and tram starts at p3 crossing p1 with a speed of x+5.5/60 km/min with total time t-3 min

Comment: $16.5$ km/h is really slow for a train (typically only when it's approaching or departing from stops). But such a speed is quite typical for a tram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On that "special day", the girl walks for an extra $12 - 3 = 9$ minutes to get to the new meeting point. The tram has travelled for $3$ minutes less than usual to get to that new meeting point. The distance of the new meeting point from the usual one is the same for both. Therefore the tram is travelling $\frac 93 = 3$ times as fast as the girl, so its speed is $(5.5)(3) = 16.5 \mathrm{km/h}$.

Addendum: as I have been asked for a solution "by equations", I shall oblige. Referencing the equations you have written as comments to my answer (please do not delete or alter them),

The first equation you have written is correct: $d = (r_0 + r_1)t$.

The second equation is incorrect. It should be $d = r_0(t - \frac 1{20} + \frac 15) + r_1(t - \frac 1{20})$. The girl starts $12 \mathrm{
min}$ (one fifth of an hour) sooner, but meets the tram $3\mathrm{
min}$ (one twentieth of an hour) sooner also. The effects of these two are opposing - starting sooner gives her more of a head start and increases the travelled distance so you add that time, but meeting the tram sooner lessens the time and decreases the travelled distance, so you must subtract that time.

Equating those two (to eliminate $d$) immediately allows one to find the ratio between $r_0$ and $r_1$.

It is unclear why you have written the term $t$ twice in the "girl component" of your second equation causing it to cancel out.

Sometimes it's important to take a step back and look at the problem in a simple fashion. Equations may cloud the issue. If it can be solved without algebra, all the better.

Comment: If you can solve it simply, why bother with equations?

Comment: Yes I understood it that way, but if I try to solve by equations.

Consider $d$, the distance between her and the tram.

Also consider $r0$ and $r1$, the speeds of her and the tram.



We have (1) -->$$d=(r_0+r_1)t$$
The second equation can be written as
$$ r_o((t-\frac{1}{20})-(t-\frac{1}{5}))+r_1(t-\frac{1}{20})=d=(r_o+r_1)t$$
which on putting $r_0=5.5$ gives
$$5.5*\frac{3}{20}=\frac{r_1}{20}+5.5t$$

How can I get the other equation involving $r_1$ and $t$?.

I have got this idea from Saketh Malyala's answer.

Comment: Just being inquisitive :P

Comment: @Soumee I've obliged, please see my edit. I maintain that solutions should be as simple as possible. :)

Answer (score 1):

Soumee,

I believe I may have an answer that is founded in equations based off your idea from before.

Set up a reference frame with left denoting the negative direction and right being positive. Place the girl's house at the origin. Using the 1-D kinematics equations for position, let the following being true:

a) $x_s = -(v_s)*t$ Where $x_s$ is Sania's position on the line and $v_s$ is the velocity of Sania.

b) $x_t = (v_t)*t - x_{0,t}$ Where $x_t$ is the position of the train on
   the line and $v_t$ is the velocity of the train and $x_{0,t}$ is the
   train's position at the time Sania usually leaves her house.

If you let the two positions equal each other and solve for $x_{0,t}$, you get an equation analogous to your equation 1 from before. In the form of my equations this is:

c) $x_{0,t} = (v_s + v_t)(t_{M})$

Where $t_{M}$ is the usual meet up time

Next, set them equal again, but this time set the new meet up time to be 3 minutes behind $t_{M}$. The following equations should come:

d)

$$-(v_s)*(t_{M}-3 min)-(12 min * v_s) =  (v_t)*(t_{M}-3 min) - x_{0,t}$$

This equality comes from the fact that they meet at the same position on the 1-D reference frame and for the fact that at t=0, Sania has already traveled for 12 minutes. Solving the equation for $v_t$ gives you the speed of the train. It should also be noted that both sides will contain equation c, so you can go ahead and cancel them on both sides of the second equality.

CHANGELOG:---------

CHANGE 1: ACCOUNTING FOR SIGN ERROR MADE (negative sign was changed to positive for $v_t$ so Sania and the train go in opposite directions)

CHANGE 2: ACCOUNTING FOR ERROR IN POSITION (equation d was reconfigured so that the train keeps its original position at time t=0 and accounts for the fact that for 12 minutes before t=0 , Sania was heading in the left direction).

CHANGE3: ADDED CLARIFICATION ON EQUATION d (elaborated on why the origin term $-(12 min * v_s)$ was put in and elaborated more on the choice for time (here t=0 is where we start the "clock" so to speak. Sania has already traveled a certain distance toward the meeting point at the time the train hits the point on the line where it usually is when Sania usually leaves).

Comment: @soumee Furthermore, I do apologize for my incorrect answer from before. I have verified this DOES indeed give the answer you got of 16.5 km/hr.

Comment: I understand your approach but I have a few doubts

1)If we equate a) and (b), we get
$$x_0=(v_s-v_t)t$$

instead of $ x_0=(v_s+v_t)t $. But $ x_0=(v_s+v_t)t $ should be the correct value as per arithmetic. I don't know if the way of arriving at this is different in kinematics.

Comment: 2)I am having problems in understanding eq (d).Plese verify if my understanding of the concept is correct: Let $x_{s1}$ be Sania's position at the line where they meet 3 min before the usual time and $x_{t1}$ be the tram's position at the line where they meet 3 min before the usual time 

$$x_{s1}=-v_s(t_M-12min)-v_s((t_M-3min)-(t_M-12min))$$
$$=>x_{s1}=-v_s(t_M-12min)-v_s(9min))$$
Similarly
$$x_{t1}=-x_0-v_T(t_M-3)$$
leading to

$$x_{s1}=x_{t1}$$

I am having difficulty in placing the different terms of eq (d) in your answer.
Thank you

Comment: Again, apologies. Was up till late last night trying to go through my work after my error from before (or early depending on how you look at it). When I did my work, noticed I threw in an extra negative sign for the train where there shouldn't be one as the train is going in the opposite direction. My post from above has been edited now to reflect this.

Comment: I also apologize, but I'm not sure what $v_s$ is in the first equation. Are you still using that as my convention for Sania's speed?

Comment: I believe you have the idea, but in reverse. The idea by using Kinematics is that the function of an object's position is denoted by $x(t)={\Delta}{x}+x_0$. Now applying this to the train meeting 3 minutes earlier, that's how you get my revised equation d where the left side and right sides both equal the position of the meeting place of Sania and the train 3 minutes earlier from the usual time. If you plug in equation c for the $x_{0,t}$ term and solve for $v_{t}$ then, that gives the right answer.

Comment: For the purposes of this problem of course, I let Sania's starting point be the origin of the 1-D coordinate system.

Comment: @Soumee Also found a new error. Post had been updated. See Changelog.

Answer (score 0):

**I would appreciate if someone could check this over for me:**

Consider $d$, the distance between her and the tram.

Also consider $r_0$ and $r_1$, the speeds of her and the tram.

We have (1) --> $d=(r_0+r_1)t$.

We also have (2) --> $d+\frac{1}{5}r_1=\frac{1}{5}r_0+(r_0+r_1)(t-\frac{1}{20})$

We know that $r_0=5.5$.

Now we subtract the equations from each other and plug in known values to get $r_1$.

Simplify the second equation a bit first.

$d=\frac{1}{5}(r_0-r_1)+(r_0+r_1)t-\frac{1}{20}({r_0+r_1})$.

Subtracting (1) from (2) gives $0=\frac{1}{5}(5.5-r_1)-\frac{1}{20}(5.5+r_1).$

Finally, we get $r_1,$ the speed of the tram, $\boxed{3.3}$ km/h.

Comment: from what i know about six flags humans can be faster than trams

Comment: wait i googled it and trams are 16 km/h i must've done something wrong

Comment: The answer is 16.5 km/h.
I didnt understand your second equation so I have formulated the second equation based on your idea. 
The first equation is fine.
The second equation can be written as
$$ r_o((t-\frac{1}{20})-(t-\frac{1}{5}))+r_1(t-\frac{1}{20})=d=(r_o+r_1)t$$
which on putting $r_0=5.5$ gives
$$5.5*\frac{3}{20}=\frac{r_1}{20}+5.5t$$

I cant get what the other equation would be.

Comment: so what messed me up.. ?

Comment: ok understood what i need to do thank you :)

Comment: welcome :D good luck in solving

Comment: Saketh, can you tell how do I get the other equation involving $r_1$ and $t$ ?Secondly,  I am not sure but you have added a term to d in eq 2. But from what I understand the distance is equal in both the cases, so nothing needs to be added to distance. Both will travel the same total distance in the second case aswell. I am not sure, but I think that is the issue.